# How to disallow any input value outside a given set using typing module

Tags: python

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
    def split(self, sep: typing.Set(-1, 0, 1) = 1):
```

Anything beside those values should throw an error (I would like this behvaiour). I just cannot find resource on how to do it.

Comment: Type hints are for enforcing types, not values. You must validate your arguments yourself within the function.

Comment: I see. I thought you can declare a type on the fly (as in Julia).  Thanks.

Comment: You can get creative with a subclass of `set` and a factory but I don't think it would worth the effort. It wouldn't be very readable either.

Answer (score 0):

To validate your arguments:

```
def split(x):
    if x not in [-1,0,1] :
           print("Error!")
           return

    #other code here

split()
```

Comment: You don't really need the `else`.